# Disposal of TreeNodes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have derived a custom `TreeNode` type, `TreeNodeEx`. In my `TreeNodeEx`, I subscribe to a `NameChanged` event, of some Value object that is assigned to it.  The lifetime of this Value is longer than the lifetime of the tree node.

My thinking is that when the tree node is removed, Value still has a reference to the tree node via the event handler delegate. So this would keep a dangling reference to the tree node.

`TreeNode` is not `IDisposable`, and there is no event or method to override in `TreeNode` to know when it is removed, and thus, when I should unhook from the event.  So, how do I know when to unhook?

```
class TreeNodeEx : TreeNode {
    private Foo m_value;
    public Foo Value {
        get { return m_value; }
        set {
            if (m_value != null) {
                m_value.NameChanged -= ValueNameChanged;
            }

            m_value = value;

            if (m_value != null) {
                m_value.NameChanged += ValueNameChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ValueNameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: TreeView was not designed to be a collection class, it is only good at displaying strings.  Trying to make it do more never works out well.  Separate the model from your view so that you just use plain TreeNodes and do whatever you need to do in your own collection class.

Comment: There isn't a way for the user to remove a node by themselves, so where ever in your code you are calling `treeView1.Nodes.Remove(...)` is when you should handle your disposal duties.

Comment: @LarsTech Duh. Overthought that one, huh? Make that an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not that I'm "storing" the values in the `TreeNodeCollection`, its just that there functionality in the `TreeNodeEx` that requires it to have a *reference* to the items it is representing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way for the user to remove a node by themselves, so where ever in your code you are calling `treeView1.Nodes.Remove(...)` is when you should handle your disposal duties.